# Jira - Updating the history

Tags: jira

is it possible to change the history of a change request? To be more clear I want to update the assignee field in the history of a change request which is closed already and put another name there. The workflow can go on with the new name, there is no problem there. But is it possible to change the history of a change request? If it is which script should we use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to change the current assignee of the jira request, but it's not possible to go into the history to change an assignee.

You can create a Jira request and they might add it in on a later patch
https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa